# Lightning components and enabling my domain in winter '16. What is the reason?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

If you are using lightning components prior winter '16 upgrade, you won't be able to use that components after upgrade is being roll out. 
http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_lightning_cruc.htm

Here is blog post about that, but doesn't give an answer on technical aspect: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/10/important-change-to-lightning-components-in-winter-16.html

Does anybody have any more detailed technical answer why is that? There must be some serious security issue, maybe XSS vulnerability or something.

Answer (score 0):

I heard the following from @zachmcelrath of skuid:

> My guess is it has something to do with trying to protect the
>   "Lightning Experience Setup menu" --- one of the Salesforce's Security
>   team's biggest concerns is protecting the Setup menu from any sort of
>   security threats, so if Lightning Apps / Components could run in the
>   same domain as the Lightning Experience Setup menu, there would be
>   opportunities for JavaScript to mess with the setup menu since they'd
>   be running in the same domain (e.g. na12.lightning.force.com).